# Code to show when the site was last updated.

Tags: wordpress

I am renewing our website's certification with HON (Health on the Net) and they now require several pages show when the site was last updated. Is there a code that I could use that I could insert on the specific pages? I'm not very good with the programming side of web so any help is greatly appreciated!
Karen

Comment: I try not to go into the templates as I am still learning. This answered worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way would be that of adding the_modified_date() to the template used by the pages where you need to show the date. You can find the docs at:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date

However, if you don't feel comfortable modifying the template files, you can probably resort to a plugin like "Last Updated Shortcode". Just install and activate the plugin, and then you can display the date of a specific page by adding the code [lastupdated] in the content editor of each of those pages.

You can find the plugin at:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/last-updated-shortcode/